# Rails 4: Dynamically change the Time method in a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, time, metaprogramming

I am trying to drill down some searches in my app using time intervals....posts in the last day, last week, last month. I am trying to be DRY and write a search controller method that will handle this for me. I am having probelms passing in the time variable. See the form below. @search_term is the search term and hidden becasue for this form as an example, all the client sees is a link saying "last 24 hours"

```
    <%= form_tag time_searches_path do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :search_task, @search_term %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :time, "24" %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :Klass, Micropost %>
        <%= submit_tag "Last 24 hours", class: 'Criteria'%>
    <% end %>
```

Then I have a helper method that is included in my search controller.....

```
  def get_time_interval time
    if time == "24"
     @time_variable = 1.day.ago
    elsif time == "week"
     @time_variable =  1.week.ago
   elsif time == "month"
    @time_variable =  1.month.ago
   end
  end
```

Then I add the time_variable into my controller action

```
 def search
   model = params[:Klass]
   klass = model.constantize
   time = params[:time]
   get_time_interval time
    @search = Sunspot.search [klass] do
     fulltext params[:search_task]
     with(:created_at).greater_than(@time_variable)
  end
 end
```

Clearly this is wrong. I assuming i need some form of metaprogramming. I am new to rails to don't really know how to proceed.

Error I get is

```
      undefined method `gsub' for nil:nilclass
```

And it highlights the line with the time variable in the controller

Comment: Looks promising @GhostRider... what is happening when you try this?

Comment: Steve, thanks - see error above

Comment: Are you sure that `@time_variable` is getting initialized after you call `get_time_interval`? You can use `puts @time_variable` to inspect the value before calling search.